# MySql Setup in Linux Docker Container Via Terraform

Tags: mysql, docker, terraform, devops

Requirement: Need to automate MySQL installation & Database creation on Linux(Ubuntu)Docker Container via Terra form.
I am doing all this stuff on my local machine & below is the Terra form configuration.

Terra form file:

```
resource "docker_container" "db-server1" {
  name  = "db-server"
  image = docker_image.ubuntu.latest
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 9093
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "docker container start dbs-my"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "docker exec dbs-my apt-get update"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "docker exec dbs-my apt-get -y install mysql-server"
  }
}
```

But in container there is no mysql service present, when i am trying to launch mysql command, i am getting below error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Terraform for this at all is a little unusual; you might look at more Docker-native tools like Docker Compose to set this up.  There are also several anti-patterns in this example: you should generally avoid installing software in running containers, and avoid running long sequences of imperative commands via Terraform, and it's usually not useful to run the bare `ubuntu` Docker image as-is.

You can run the [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead:

```
resource "docker_image" "mysql" {
  name = "mysql:8"
}

resource "random_password" "mysql_root_password" {
  length = 16
}

resource "docker_container" "mysql" {
  name = "mysql"
  image = "${docker_image.mysql.latest}"
  env {
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = "${random_password.mysql_root_password.result}"
  }
  mounts {
    source = "/some/host/mysql/data/path"
    target = "/var/lib/mysql/data"
    type = "bind"
  }
  ports {
    internal = 3306
    external = 3306
  }
}
```

If you wanted to do further setup on the created database, you could use the [MySQL provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html)

```
provider "mysql" {
  endpoint = "127.0.0.1:3306" # the "external" port
  username = "root"
  password = "${random_password.mysql_root_password.result}"
}

resource "mysql_database" "db" {
  name = "db"
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to use both in single script (MySql docker container setup) & DB creation. I tried this but i have found that Terraform currently has a limitation where it can't create an entire stack like this where a resource has to be created in order to configure another provider.

Comment: @TusharJain https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies#manage-explicit-dependencies You can use implicit dependencies with depends_on

Comment: lets say my mysql container is stopped. On refreshing the state , 
Its able to get the current state of mysql container(resource named mysql above)
 but it fails to get the current state of the db(resource named db above)  , because it unable to connect to my mysql db . 

is there any work around to this?